# Need help with evaluating the expectation of a complex Gaussian random variable conditioned on an inequality

Tags: probability, integration

I am trying to evaluate the expectation of a complex Gaussian random variable. My problem is as follows:
I have two independent random variables $\alpha\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\beta)$ and $w\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,\sigma^2)$. $\mathcal{CN}$ stands for complex Gaussian random variable. I want to evaluate the follwing expectation 
\begin{equation}\mathbb{E}\left\{|\alpha|^2\;\vert\ |\alpha+w|<\tau\right\}\end{equation} and $\tau>0$.

I tried evaluating this but couldn't make any progress. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even an outline of the steps to be followed would be of a great help.

Thank you.